# I'm getting error in Builder::getAuthIdentifierName() after register in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

My application in Laravel is presenting the following error after registering:
"BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthIdentifierName()"
The error only appears after performing the authentication. If I clear my browser's cache, the error disappears and the application works normally.
I already saw other answers in StackOverflow and other sites, but none of them solved my problem. What could be happening?

Here is my User.php file:

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'cpf', 'name', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'auth', 'authy_id', 'api_token', 'block', 'blocked_at', 'session'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

My code that does authentication is here:

```
public function auth($session, $gtag){
    $user = User::where('session', $session)->first();
    if(isset($user) && !empty($user)){
        Auth::login($user);

        //$time = decrypt($user->session);
        $user->session = NULL;
        $user->save();

        setcookie('_ga', $gtag, (time() + 605800), '/', 'bmydomain.com');
        setcookie('_gat_gtag_UA_115432851_1', '1', (time() + 605800), '/', 'mydomain.com');

        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
    }
    else{
        return redirect($this->redirectNotAuth);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(isset($user) && !empty($user)){` equal `if($user !== null) {`

Comment: see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: is your `users` table has id primary key field. if not then specify primary key field in your model `protected $primaryKey = 'yourPrimaryKeyField';`

Comment: I was able to solve the problem! I flush the application cache and removed the configuration cache. `php artisan cache: clear` then `php artisan config: clear`. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

On Kernel.php file use:

`'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,`

instead of

`'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,`